# Rails: How to have dynamic attribute in a blog section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

I have a software-DB architecture/design problem related to a blog application. Suppose I want to provide the user with the feature of adding sections in a page. Each page section can have many components which vary, depending on standard practices in web development.

For example:

- A section with a paragraph and an image OR two such components OR
- A section with four images or one Gallery OR two Galleries
- A section with two paragraphs OR
- A section with video and paragraph etc

One approach I can take is to build each type of component type, its MVC components, and use it when ever I need. But I am feeling from a design perspective if I have 1000 such components, I will have 1000 tables in active record. That's not efficient.

I am feeling the need of dynamic attributes generation OR using same table to store different types of components and just dynamically changing the view depending on a type attribute OR a factory pattern implementation(which I feel is a good candidate here).

I will really appreciate if you can help me out with this design or suggest some other ways of handling dynamic components generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the most flexibility for your sections by storing possible configurations of a section as a serialized hash in your table.

Let's say you have a `sections` table with a field `config` of type `text`. The `Section` model will declare `serialize :config` and will automatically `serialize` / `deserialize` any hash you assign to an instance of `section.config`.

This `config` hash will have attributes necessary for the layout of your sections e.g.

```
section.config = {
  components: [:paragraph, :image, :image, video],
  # ... and any other such config settings you will need in your view to render this section as you want it
}
```

Now perhaps you'll instantiate a `section` model and render it in a show view, and to render each component of the section, you'd have one partial for each component. This way, you can iterate over `section.config[:components]` and render the partial by that name e.g.

```
section.config[:components].each do |component|
  render partial: component, locals: { content: 'some content for the paragraph' }
  # the above would render, for example, the 'paragraph' partial
end
```

With a hash of this nature, you can let the user create their sections as custom as they want, picking predefined components (for which you have partials) and adding them to sections in any combination therein.

You can even go further than the above approach and create a `Component` model whom the `Section` model will be associated to many instances i.e `Section has_many :components`. With that, instead of `Section` having a `config` field storing an array of `:components` it will have many `Component` models that it can iterate over and access a richer set of attributes it can use when rendering the whole section. That will afford you the use of nested fields provided by Rails form helpers where you can build a form that your users will use to create complex sections and be able to reorder them, name them, add styles, and so on (given that you add fields to the component for storing all this configuration data). With this final approach you can use the Component table to store content data per component of a section.

Comment: Thanks so much! :) I used the latter approach by creating a component(in my case named widget with multiple fields and css fields associated with each and a type field which specifies what type the widget is: paragraph, image, video etc) Using the type I dynamically provide the users a form they can fill which has fields related to the type of widget, so that only necessary fields will be generated. At the end, in the views, for each section I iterate over its widgets and dynamically generate divs depending upon the type.

Comment: That's awesome @SauravPrakash way to go!